# Is there a correct order to stack Neutral Density with a Circular Polariser filter?

Tags: filters, filter-stacking

I like stacking ND and CP filters and I never really payed attention to the order I stack them.  I was just reading a "professional hint" on the [LEE website](http://www.leefilters.com/index.php/camera/polariser) where it states that " the Polariser must be placed in front of the polyester filters"

2 of my filters are made of glass but I am not not 100% sure about the 3rd (Hoya 77mm Circular Polarizer (HMC) Multi-Coated Glass Filter, Hoya 77mm Neutral Density x400 (ND) 2.7 Hoya Multi-Coated (HMC) Glass Filter, Tiffen 77mm 0.9 ND Filter (Glass?))

Materials aside, how should I be stacking my ND and CP filters? CP first or last?

Will I get different results when stacking one way or the other?