# Does the order matter in filter stacking?

Tags: filters, film, color-filters, filter-stacking

Suppose I want to shoot a bright location inside, with a shallow DOF, where the temperature is very warm, and on film.

Easy, I just grab my ND and 80A filters.

Now what? Do I put my ND filter on first, my color correcting first, or does it not matter?

I've seen some questions that come close like [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40403/is-there-a-correct-order-to-stack-neutral-density-with-a-circular-polariser-filt) and [this one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13614/is-it-possible-to-use-a-polarizer-and-a-nd-filter-at-the-same-time), but that is just for one specific case.

I want to know in general:

**Does order matter when it comes to filters?**

Just holding them over each other and looking into a light source does *seem* to show a *slight* difference; however, since it is on film I'm not sure which is going to produce a more desirable look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If one were multicoated (i.e. is less reflective) and the other is not, then put the filter with better antireflective treatment closest to the lens for the following reason: reflections from the first surface of the front filter won't affect the picture, but if placed in the middle of the stack, some of that could be bounced off the front filter back into the camera. *However, the difference should be miniscule, with decent filters.*

If one filter is smaller diameter, place it closer to the lens to reduce vignetting.

You did not mention polarizers, but a CPL should be on the outside to avoid showing striations in a filter in front of it; see http://www.glassonweb.com/articles/article/742/. Again, this should not be a problem with good quality filters.